# Is destructor of empty unique_ptr w/o custom deleter trivial

Tags: c++, destructor, c++14, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Given a code (really pseudocode):

```
struct A { /* ... */ }; // assume is non-trivial
struct B { /* ... */ }; // assume is non-trivial

using UA = std::unique_ptr< A >;
using UB = std::unique_ptr< B >;

union U
{

    UA a;
    UB b;

};

U u{std::make_unique< A >(/* init */)};
u.a = nullptr; // destructor of underlying type A called
// u.a.~UA(); // destructor of smart pointer itself
::new (&U.b) UB{std::make_unique< B >(/* init */)};
```

Is it permittable to omit calling of destructor for `U::a` member? The question is inspired by following [quote](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/~unique_ptr) regarding `std::unique_ptr::~unique_ptr`:

> If get() == nullptr there are no effects.

May I take it that the d-tor in this case is trivial (in described below sense)?

I think internal (and sole in case of `std::unique_ptr` w/o custom deleter) data member (say `p`) of `std::unique_ptr< T >` is of type `T *`. After assigning `p = nullptr;` it seems permittable to do exactly nothing with such a `std::unique_ptr` in order to use its storage for another purposes. Is it right conclusion?

Comment: @deviantfan Its just an optimization. In real life portion of code (heap-variant class) I should swap two `U`-like structures. There is no placement `::new` in that code, and, therefore, there shouldn't be explicit calls of destructors (just idiom).

Answer (score 2):

> May I take it that the d-tor in this case is trivial?

No.  A trivial destructor is a formal defined term in C++ and a non-empty destructor is never trivial. Triviality is a compile-time property of a type, so a destructor that has to perform a run-time test and conditionally call a deleter cannot be trivial.

However, it is always valid to omit destroying an object if the program's correctness doesn't rely on the destructor's effects.

[basic.life] p4:

> For an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor, the program is not required to call the destructor explicitly before the storage which the object occupies is reused or released; however, if there is no explicit call to the destructor or if a *delete-expression* (5.3.5) is not used to release the storage, the destructor shall not be implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior.

Since the `unique_ptr` has no side effects when it is empty the program does not depend on it, so it is OK to omit running the destructor.

Comment: `s/doesnot not/does not/` Double negation is initial statement itself.